# array.map() is returning elements all together in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array.prototype.map

```js
const test = () = {

const array = ['hello', 'myNameIs']

return (

{
array.map((arr) => (
  <div>{arr}</div>
  <button>Edit</button>
  )
}

)

}
```

This .map() method is not working as I intended.

With the code, I was trying to get

```js
hello [button]
myNameIs [button]
```

like this.

But when I actually render the code, I get

```js
hello MynameIs [button]
```

In this kind of situation, How can I change the .map() statement?

Should I use an index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the correct syntax for the arrow function
It should be like
`const test = ()=>{}`
React component JSX should return one parent container try wrapping it like:

```js
 const Test = () => {
    const array = ["hello", "myNameIs"];

    return (
      <>
        {array.map((arr) => {
          return (
            <>
              <div>{arr}</div>
              <button>Edit</button>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </>
    )
  }
```

Here is the working code sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-easley-jxiei?file=/src/App.js:57-336

I Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at below example, I created it almost by your code, it is working as you expected without problem.

```js
function App() {
  const array = ['hello', 'myNameIs'];
  return array.map(item => (
    <div key={item}>
      {item} <button>Edit</button>
    </div>
  ));
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you saeed. Nice to see detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Create the button inside the `div` tag. Also you can use style to align the items as required

```
array.map((arr) => (
  <div>{arr} <button>Edit</button></div>
 )
```

Comment: Again, got the same answer :( IDK what is going on!!

Answer (score 0):

```
const test = () = {
  const array = ['hello', 'myNameIs']
  return (

  {array.map((item,key) => (
    <div key={item}>{item}</div><button>Edit</button>
  )})
}
```

Comment: Thank you Akshay! I forgot to write return !